# Is it possible to add a custom page to a free Wordpress site?

Tags: php, customization, wordpress.com-hosting

I'm trying to add a custom page to my Wordpress website. I found this link, which says that I need to add the template to the theme folder, but I have a free Wordpress website, so I don't have access to that folder :/

Is it possible to add a custom page to a free Wordpress site (http://rebelradio9100.wordpress.com) or do I need to upgrade to a paid one for that?

Comment: Welcom to WPSE. Unfortuantely we do not offer support for sites hosted with wordpress.com. They have their own support forum. Please feel free to contact them directly. Please see [ask] and [help] and learn what is on and off topic here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

WordPress.com doesn't offers to create any page templates or Theme Editing offers. You've to be upgrade your service or have to be self Hosted WordPress Website.